# An object reference error messages is required for the non static field or property method

Tags: object, methods, properties, reference, non-static

I have one problem, as shown below, although both are public and BUS 2 class has a reference to DAO, but still an object reference error messages is required for the non static field or property method.

[Image DAO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ2Hv.png)
[Image BUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFSSP.png)

Comment: Post code as text please, not as screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

add static 
ex: 
 public static SYS_TaiKhoan GetTaiKhoan(string username)
        {
            return HeThongDao.GetTaiKhoan(username);
        }